# Spring @Import is ignoring @ConditionalOnBean defined on the same class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to set up a custom Spring auto-configuration.

The custom auto-configuration needs to import a regular Spring configuration but only if a Bean is present in context.

So far a simple `@ConditionalOnBean` on the configuration to be imported should do it as the doc clearly [state it](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html):

> If a @Configuration class is marked with @Conditional, all of the @Bean methods, @Import annotations, and @ComponentScan annotations associated with that class will be subject to the conditions.

I don't want to set a `@ConditionalOnBean` on the regular Spring configuration (which is not in the auto-configuration module)

So I created a second Configuration class which is only used to conditionaly import my "old regular configuration"

Here is the relevant code.

- Custom Autoconfiguration class

```java
package myproject.lib.autoconfigure

@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(RabbitAutoConfiguration.class)
@Import(ImportSpecificConfig.class)
public class ObjectStorageFacadeAutoConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(HttpClient.class)
    public HttpClient httpClient() {
        return HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    }
    
    //a few other beans...
}
```

- Importer configuration:

```java
package myproject.lib.autoconfigure

@ConditionalOnBean(ConnectionFactory.class)
@Configuration
@Import(SpecificConfig.class)
public class ImportSpecificConfig {
   @Bean
   public SomeBean aBean(){
     return new SomeBean();
   }
}
```

- Old regular configuration (which also imports a bunch of things)

```java
package other.lib

@Configuration
@Import(CommonConfiguration.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ObjectStorageRabbitQueueProperties.class)
@ComponentScan
public class SpecificConfig {

}
```

The expected behaviour for me is to not process the `@Import(SpecificConfig.class)` in the `ImportSpecificConfig.class` when no `ConnexionFactory` bean is present.
Also it shouldn't instantiate in context the `SomeBean` bean.

I then wrote a test:

```java
class ObjectStorageFacadeAutoConfigurationTest {
    private final ApplicationContextRunner contextRunner = new ApplicationContextRunner()
            .withConfiguration(AutoConfigurations.of(ObjectStorageFacadeAutoConfiguration.class));
    @Test
    void autoConfiguredCacheManagerIsInstrumented() {
        this.contextRunner
                .run((context) -> {
                    assertThat(context).hasSingleBean(HttpClient.class);
                });
    }
}
```

This test fails at starting the context. Arguing that I'm missing some beans in context required to instantiate a bean defined in... `SpecificConfig` package.

So my understanding (which I could confirm by using debuger) is that the `@Import` annotation in `ImportSpecificConfig` class **is used** even when the context does **not** have any bean matching with the `@ConditionalOnBean` condition. This trigger the `@ComponentScan` and `@Import` annotations from the old regular configuration, which fails the test because required beans are not present in context (which is intended).

By the way, the `SomeBean` is actually not instantiated, as expected.

The weird thing is that if I use the `@ConditionalOnBean` on the old regular `SpecificConfig` configuration class, the expected behaviour happens: the `@Import(CommonConfiguration.class)` is not activated, and then I don't have any problem with context initialization.

But of course it's not a way to do things correctly, since I'm not suppose to be able to change the lib source code.

**tl;dr;**
the `@Import` in a `@Configuration` annotated class is evaluated, even if the `@Configuration` class has a `@ConditionalOnBean` which evaluates to false. And the bean defined in this `@Configuration` class are not instantiated, which confirms the fact that `@ConditionalOnBean` evaluates to false.
It seems that the @ComponentScan is the real problem. I believe it shouldn't be evaluated, but it is.

Here is a simple reproductible example
https://github.com/fdeguibert/sample

What don't I understand? Is there any trick about this `@ConditionalOnBean` that I don't see or is it a bad behaviour?

Comment: I'm not sure that @ConditionalOnMissingBean is supposed to be used on a configuration class.

Comment: hum, the annotation @ConditionalOnBean has a `@Target(value={TYPE,METHOD})` so it should be alright. Beside there is a @ConditionalOnBean on  a few class in org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure package.
So it sounds ok. ([CacheMetricsAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/cache/CacheMetricsAutoConfiguration.java) for example)

Comment: Conditions have two phases, `PARSE_CONFIGURATION` and `REGISTER_BEAN`. Bean-based conditions are only active in the latter. When `ImportSpecificConfig` is parsed, `@ConditionalOnBean(ConnectionFactory.class)` does not prevent `@Import(SpecificConfig.class)` from being processing, however tracking of the import chain should prevent beans defined in `SpecificConfig` from being registered. Unfortunately, there aren't enough details in your question for me to identify what's going wrong. Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I give you that ASAP

Comment: well @AndyWilkinson I'm sadly unable to give you a reproducible example since... the one I just wrote is actually working as expected....

So I guess my problem is actually hidden in some spaghetti configuration on the real project.... Thanks anyway, I should investigate a bit more. If I find out anything leading to my behaviour and can reproduce it, I'll let you know

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I finally reproduced the problem.
Here is a minimal reproducible example. https://github.com/fdeguibert/sample
Adding the @ComponentScan on `OldConfig` introduced the problem. But from my understanding, it shouldn't since it should be filtered with the @ConditionalOnBean also....
Thanks.

Comment: The real trouble is with the test "without TriggerBean". 

It should not activate the @ComponentScan and then I should not get the bean in context. 
The other test is a "normal" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more digging and thanks to @AndyWilkinson, I realized my mistake.

@ConditionalOnBean is effectively a REGISTER_BEAN phase condition. So the @Import ignore it, and obviously @ComponentScan ignore it as well since this annotation is needed during PARSE_CONFIGURATION phase.

So if my undestanding is correct, a @ConditionalOnBean applied at a @Configuration type level will actually be used by Beans defined in this @Configuration class and not by the class itself.

A good way to check it was to replace the @ConditionalOnBean with a `@Conditional(FalseCondition.class)`

And trying to define the `FalseCondition` in two ways:

- first:

```java
public class FalseCondition implements ConfigurationCondition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public ConfigurationPhase getConfigurationPhase() {
        return ConfigurationPhase.REGISTER_BEAN;
    }
}
```

-> produce the same result as the @ConditionalOnBean : @Import is evaluated

- second :

```java
public class FalseCondition implements ConfigurationCondition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public ConfigurationPhase getConfigurationPhase() {
        return ConfigurationPhase.PARSE_CONFIGURATION;
    }
}
```

-> @Import is **not** evaluated. since this condition applies during parse configuration phase.